# ASP .NET Web Forms - Why is custom control's property setter not called by parent using data binding expression?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Why are my custom control's property setters not getting called by the parent page when using [data binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions#---data-binding-expression) to set the control's properties? The setters ***are* called** when using a constant to set the control's properties.

**MyPage.aspx:**

```
...
<foo:MyControl ID="bar" runat="server" MyProperty="<%# Thirteen %>" />
...
```

**MyPage.aspx.cs:**

```
...
protected int Thirteen { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Thirteen = 13;
        DataBind();
    }
}
...
```

**MyControl.ascx.cs:**

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get => (int)(ViewState["MyProperty"] ?? 0);
        set => ViewState["MyProperty"] = value;
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the setter, and it's never called when I load the page.

***However***, if I change `MyPage.aspx` from/to this, it works:

```
<foo:MyControl ID="bar" runat="server" MyProperty="13" />
```

Is it possible to have the setter called using the data binding expression? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Identical code works fine for me. Are you sure you're looking at the correct usercontrol code file?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... I left out a key piece of control code where I was overriding OnDataBinding without calling its base implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing...

My ***actual*** code for `MyControl.ascx.cs` was more appropriately the following:

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get => (int)(ViewState["MyProperty"] ?? 0);
        set => ViewState["MyProperty"] = value;
    }

    // THIS IS THE KEY
    protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
    {
        // bunch of stuff, but never calling base.OnDataBinding(e)
    }
}
```

After adding `base.OnDataBinding(e);` to the overridden method, everything worked as expected.